# Function Which Returns Sum of Diagonal Elements of 2D Array in C++

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

I am required to create a function which calculates the sum of elements on the diagonal of the matrix with signature `int diagonal(int array[4][4])`

Here's what I've tried:

```
int diagonal(int array[4][4]){
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j < 4; j++){
            if (i == j){
            sum = sum + array[i,j];
            }
        }
    }
return sum;
}



#include <iostream>

extern int diagonal(int[][]);
int main (){
    int array[4][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4}};
    std::cout << "The sum is: " << diagonal(array) << std::endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

Yet it produces some error messages which I don't seem to understand why those are the case:

```
main-1-1.cpp:3:27: error: multidimensional array must have bounds for all dimensions except the first
 extern int diagonal(int[][]);
                           ^
main-1-1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main-1-1.cpp:6:47: error: too many arguments to function ‘int diagonal()’
  std::cout << "The sum is: " << diagonal(array) << std::endl; 
                                               ^
main-1-1.cpp:3:12: note: declared here
 extern int diagonal(int[][]);
            ^
function-1-1.cpp: In function ‘int diagonal(int (*)[4])’:
function-1-1.cpp:8:14: error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
    sum = sum + array[i,j];
```

Can someone please explain to me regarding that?

Comment: Do they only want the sum of the top-left to bottom-right diagonal?

Comment: Change `sum = sum + array[i,j];` to  `sum = sum + array[i][j];`

Comment: @0x499602D2 yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int diagonal(int array[][4]){
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j < 4; j++){
            if (i == j){
            sum = sum + array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
return sum;
}



#include <iostream>

extern int diagonal(int[][4]);
int main (){
    int array[4][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4}};
    std::cout << "The sum is: " << diagonal(array) << std::endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

you can put any number in the first [ ] but the compiler will ignore it. When passing a vector as parameter you must specify all dimensions but the first one.
in short, you don't need to pass a value in a function declaration for the first [ ]

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

the answer to this is here [Passing a 2D array to a C++ function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function)

try this way instead its a little simpler

```
#include <iostream>
int diagonal(int array[][4])
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int I = 0; I < 4; I++)
    {
        sum += array[I][I];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int array[4][4] = {{1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}};
    std::cout << "sum is " << diagonal(array) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This sounds so bad, but if this answers your question, could you please mark this as  the answer and upvote me? I'm trying to build reputation for bounties